# How to store username entered into database table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to store username entered during login in the table Login Details. I am keeping track of users trying to login into the application. My code crashes at conn.Open. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have written in Homecontroller:

```
public  ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }                     
            var wwid = ActiveDirectoryUserHelper.returnWWid(model.UserName, model.UserName.Substring(model.UserName.IndexOf("\\")+1), model.Password);
            if(wwid==null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UserId"] = model.UserName.Substring(model.UserName.IndexOf("\\") + 1); 
                Session["UserPassword"] = model.Password;
                ViewBag.userId = Crypto.EncryptData(model.UserName.Substring(model.UserName.IndexOf("\\") + 1));
                ViewBag.pwd = Crypto.EncryptData(model.Password);
            }

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = XYZ,1433;initial catalog=Application;integrated security=True");

            string sql = "INSERT INTO LoginDetails (username) values (@username)";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = model.UserName;
            //cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = model.UserName;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return View("Management");

        }
```

Comment: are you pasting some fake connection string?

Comment: yeah here i have changed the connection string..

Comment: if `conn.Open` crashes, there's high chance the connection string is wrong

Comment: ohh ok. I am giving connection string at web.config the same connection string i am using here. Any other way to use it?

Comment: do you have a computer named **xyz** and has database named **application**?

Comment: i have used the exact connection string from we config file. Here due to security reasons i changed the connection string

Comment: *Crypto.EncryptData(model.Password)* **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Your users deserve and expect good security.

Comment: give us exception and inner exception you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of your code:

using System.Web.Configuration; 
Put this in Web.Config:

```
 <connectionStrings >
<add
     name="myConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

and where you want to setup the connection variable:

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution  as I got clarity on usage of sql connection. But I am still getting exception as "System.invalidOperationException" on SqlConnection con

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with the connection string you are using.

Make sure you are passing correct ServerName and database name.

Also please double check if you want to use Windows Authentication or have any user configured in the database to login with.

You can also check the following URL to know more about the connection string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

If you are still facing the error, please share the error detail here.

Comment: I am still getting System.InvalidOperationException at conn

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx